# How to convert sql query to entityframework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a SQL now i want to convert it to entityframework query. Please check the code bellow. its seems bit confusing to me. Anyone can help me to convert this query to c# entityframework style?

SQL:

```
select  TOP 10 CAST(RIGHT(ML_ItemId, LEN(ML_ItemId) - 3) as bigint)  as PrimaryKey
from ThirdPartyData
where site_id='MLA' AND IsGapChecked  IS NULL
order by PrimaryKey DESC
```

C#

```
using (var ctx = new ML_DbEntities())
{
    var Data = ctx.ThirdPartyData.Take(10).ToList(); //how can i write query here?    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to translate the query into LINQ.  I highly recommend [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/) for this.  It has a lot of built in tutorials and you can test your query without compiling.  I can't know for sure without seeing the data types in you `ThirdPartyData` class, but for this query you probably want as follows.

```cs
using (var ctx = new ML_DbEntities())
{
    var data = from item in ctx.ThirdPartyData
               where item.site_id == "MLA" && !IsGapChecked.HasValue
               let PrimaryKey = item.ML_ItemId.Right(item.ML_ItemId.Length - 3) as long
               orderby PrimaryKey
               select PrimaryKey;

    var top10 = data.Take(10);
}
```

Also, I **strongly** advise against using `ToList`.  It's rarely necessary and it can cause serious performance problems.